# Adding contact to gmail programatically by python and django through send mail

Tags: python, django, email

i want my user to add my mail id to his mail contacts if he clicks a link which i have send to him.
how can i do that???

here my code

```
def send_mail_tousers(firstname,confirmation_id,email):
    subject, from_email, to = 'Thank you for Signing Mysite.','example@gmail.com', email
    text_content = 'This is an important message.'
    html_content = render_to_string('verify.html',{'name':firstname,'id':confirmation_id})
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content,'BOSS<example@gmail.com>', [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    return msg.send()
```

By this i can send an HTML content mail to my user.

Comment: I do not think such a functionality exists in most mail clients, however you could send a vCard.

Comment: no Cilyan there is... I have seen somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Most mail clients either do that automatically or they allow to add a mail contact with a single click of a button in the UI.

You can improve the chances by attaching a vCard to the mail; most mail clients recognize these and can import more information from them than just the name and email address.

Comment: What i want is, from the user perspective it should be a link or button. If he clicks it, need to add my id to his contacts automatically. is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so. Most mail clients treat mail content as hostile (viruses, spam), so I'd be very surprised if you could "remote control" the mail client from inside a mail body.

Comment: even http://email-checker.net use this, allow you to create a acc. with fake one then ask for verification.