# how to validate email whether is active or not using validate_email module in python

Tags: python

I used validate_email module in python to check whether a user's email id is exist or not for my web application.
But it returns True always.

here is my code

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',check_mx=True) #Checking if the host has SMPT Server
```

Then i tried

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',verify=True) # Checking if the host has SMPT Server and the email really exists
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to check whether an email address really exists. Mail servers simply don't return this information anymore (because spammers used it to collect lists of recipients that way).

Even actually sending a mail doesn't help since most mail server will accept such mail and then throw it away.

Comment: ok... is there any possible way to Add contact to gmail programatically by python and django through send mail??

Comment: Please ask a new question for this, giving some details what you want to achieve and what you have.

Comment: i already asked. But no one gave me an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459698/adding-contact-to-gmail-programatically-by-python-and-django-through-send-mail

Comment: @ManikandanV So in your application it is good idea to add "email verification" feature.

Comment: The usual approach is to send a mail with a link to the given email address and then activate the account only when the link is visited.

Comment: @AaronDigulla you means "open source google analytics"? is there any other way?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: No. I mean all those web sites where you can join which send you a confirmation email.